# Python How to convert existing native dict to a custom dict object?

Tags: python

let's say I have the following custom `dict` class

```
class Entity(dict):
    ...
```

And I have some a normal native dict obj returned from a method:

```
dict_obj = retrieve_data(...)
```

How do I wrap the `dict_obj` with the `Entity` class? In other words convert the `dict_obj` into an Entity class instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are able to construct a `dict` from another `dict`...

```py
wrapped = Entity(dict_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that `dict_obj = Entity(retrieve_data(...))`. Then into your class constructor, you set the properties with the retrieve_data value

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I could have done it in... stupid me:

```
entity_instance = Entity(**dict_obj)
```